# fire jquery .animate oninput only once

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/nFFuD/

I'm trying to animate the search field in this example using jquery, making it move to the top of it's containing div oninput. I was originally using scriptaculous effect.move to do this, but I couldn't make the event only fire once, so if someone kept typing after the first keystroke, the effect would stop and start again from it's current position in the animation for each additional keystroke, which is stupid. I'm new to new to using jquery so please, take it easy if I'm not making very much sense.

EDIT: The example that ocanal posted definitely works, but for some reason it's not working for me when I apply it - here's what I currently have so far - also trying to fade a div on the same event

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<title>Untitled</title>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#search').keypress(function() {

    $(this).animate({
    top: '0',
  });

    $('#icon).fadeOut('slow', function() {

    }); 

});​

</script>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    border: #000 1px solid;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 960px;
    height: 800px;
}

input {
    outline: none;
}

#icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 370px;
    width: 200px;
}

#search {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 230px;
            width: 500px;           
}

</style>
</head>
<body>  
<div id="container">
    <img id="icon" src="icon.png" alt="icon">           
    <input id="search" type="text" autofocus="autofocus">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`change` works like `blur`, so you should do that with keypress event I think,

```
$('#search').keypress(function() {

    $(this).animate({
    top: '0',
  });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ocanal/nFFuD/7/

---

**EDIT:**

the code you shared is not working, because you should initialize event functions when dom is ready, you don't need to use it in jsFiddle, because you can select the time when script will work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//your functions.
});
```

than it will work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').keypress(function() {

      $(this).animate({
      top: '0',
    });

      $('#icon').fadeOut('slow', function() {

      }); 

  });
});
```

[and here is your working code](http://jsfiddle.net/ocanal/TA6mL/)

Comment: this works perfectly - check my edit on the question though I'm having a few issues still

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors with your syntax. Try this:

```
$('#search').change(function() {

    $(this).animate({
    top: '0'
  });

});​
```

- There shouldn't be a `+=`. This means that you will add zero to the current top position and animate to that. `0` animates to the actual top.
- There shouldn't be a comma after the top property
- You need to close the parenthesis on the `animate` function.
- `$('this')` should be `$(this)`. If you pass it in quotes, it will actually look for an `<this>` element which is of course not anywhere on your page because that isnt valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You had a few syntax errors going; when writing code, I would suggest the use of Firebug or even the Developer Tools in Chrome/IE9 to catch this errors. This code works just fine:

```
$('#search').on('keyup',function(){
    $(this).animate({
        top:0
    });                  
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a few problems with your script. Here's a working version for what I think you want to do: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nFFuD/10/)

```
$('#search').change(function() {
 $(this).animate({
   top: '0'
 })
})
```

First, to call the element inside the function, it's `$(this)` not `$('this')`. When something's in quotes, it's referencing a specific element. Without quotes, it's a variable.

You also need to get rid of the trailing comma after `top: '0'`. It will work fine in modern browsers but IE will not allow it.

You were also missing a closing bracket inside your animate function. You should be using console to spot these errors. Firebug in Firefox or, if you're using Chrome, right click the page and click "Inspect element." Console helps you debug by showing you errors. You can also send alerts there using `console.log()`.